# Activiti engine intergation with custom user & group data table

Tags: mysql, workflow, activiti

My company has their own database and it contains user and group tables.I am creating a workflow manager using Activiti API also i am using Activiti-REST. I need to fetch user data and group data from my company database instead of using ACT_ID _USER and ACT_ID_GROUP. I searched through internet and post in their forum but i didnt get any sensible answers.

In the forum they suggest to use LDAP but i dont have touch LDAP.

I went through activiti source.can i just modify its iBATIS mapping files related to ACT_ID _USER.Will it work. Or their any better approach. Also activiti-rest api must work according to our own tables.

Please can some one show some good references regarding to this.

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement the interface org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.SessionFactory and return the type of org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.Session appropiate (org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.UserIdentityManager.class or org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.GroupIdentityManager.class), then you have to create your own User/Group Manager (usually extending the org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.UserEntityManager or org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.GroupEntityManager).

Finally you have to register your Custom Session Factories on your processEngineConfiguration, for more info (a little outdated because in 5.13 the session types changed) is available on [this blog post](http://developer4life.blogspot.com/2012/02/activiti-authentication-and-identity.html)